# List of all tables with a relationship to a given table or view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server is there a command to return a list of all tables with a relationship to a given table or view?

EDIT: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: what version of SQL Server please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005 and up, use something like:

```
SELECT
    name, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Table'
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys
WHERE 
    referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('Your-referenced-table-name-here')
```

Comment: just need to replace your table name instead of Your-referenced-table-name-here DONT touch other like Table

Answer (score 2):

```
-- To find all the foreign keys established to a table!
-- Columns: FKTABLE_NAME, FKCOLUMN_NAME
sp_fkeys @pktable_name='your table name here'
```

Answer (score 2):

Say your table name is TableX. If you want to know all foreign key relationships (columns of TableX referenced in other tables and columns of other tables referenced in TableX) you could do this:

```
select name 'ForeignKeyName', 
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 'RefrencedTable',
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'ParentTable'
from sys.foreign_keys
where referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableX') or 
    parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableX')
```