# How I can get the name of tables has relation with specific table using Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How I can get the name of tables has a relation with a specific table using Entity Framework C#?

```
   List<string> results = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT name, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('" + currentmodel + "')").ToList();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of all tables with a relationship to a given table or view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732356/list-of-all-tables-with-a-relationship-to-a-given-table-or-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `EF SqlQuery` + `sys.foreign_keys join sys.tables` to do it.

```
public IList<ForeignTableViewModl> QueryForeignTable(string tableName)
{
    using(var db = new Db())
    {
        var sql = @"
select
    fk.name as [FkName],
    tp.name as [ParentTable],
    tr.name as [RefrencedTable]
from sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join sys.tables tp on fk.parent_object_id = tp.object_id
inner join sys.tables tr on fk.referenced_object_id = tr.object_id
where tp.name = @p0
    ";
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<ForeignTableViewModl>(sql, tableName).ToList();
    }

}

public class ForeignTableViewModl
{
    public string FkName { get; set; }  
    public string ParentTable { get; set; } 
    public string RefrencedTable { get; set; }  
}
```

and it'll get result of northwind demo db like :

[image]

---

> it's done but this query return just top 3 FK I want to return all FK

```
public IList<ForeignTableViewModl> QueryForeignTable(string tableName)
{
    using(var db = new Db())
    {
        var sql = @"
select
    fk.name as [FkName],
    tp.name as [ParentTable],
    tr.name as [RefrencedTable]
from sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join sys.tables tp on fk.parent_object_id = tp.object_id
inner join sys.tables tr on fk.referenced_object_id = tr.object_id
where tp.name = @p0 or tr.name = @p0
    ";
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<ForeignTableViewModl>(sql, tableName).ToList();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it's done but this query return just top 3 FK I want to return all FK

Comment: return just Fk that exist as col name in parent table but i have reltion many_to_many