# How to get a list of tables that have one-on-one relationship to a given table in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, relational-database

Is there a way to get a list of tables that have one-on-one relationship to a given table in SQLite3?

For example, here table `ab` has a one-on-one relationship with both table `abc` and `abd`. Is there a query or queries to return `abc` and `abd` for the given table name `ab`?

```
-- By default foreign key is diabled in SQLite3
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; 

CREATE TABLE a (
    aid          INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    bid          INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE ab (
    aid          INTEGER,
    bid          INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (aid, bid)
    FOREIGN KEY (aid)  REFERENCES a(aid)
    FOREIGN KEY (bid)  REFERENCES b(bid)
);

-- tables 'ab' and 'abc' have a one-on-one relationship
CREATE TABLE abc (
    aid          INTEGER,
    bid          INTEGER,
    name         TEXT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (aid, bid)  FOREIGN KEY (aid, bid)  REFERENCES ab(aid, bid)
);

-- tables 'ab' and 'abd' have a one-on-one relationship
CREATE TABLE abd (
    aid          INTEGER,
    bid          INTEGER,
    value        INTEGER       CHECK( value > 0 ),
    PRIMARY KEY (aid, bid)  FOREIGN KEY (aid, bid)  REFERENCES ab(aid, bid)
);

CREATE TABLE w (
    id           INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY
);
```

The following tedious precedure may get me the list of tables I want:

1. Get primary keys for table `ab`:

   `SELECT l.name FROM pragma_table_info('ab') as l WHERE l.pk > 0;`
2. get foreign keys for other tables (this case is for table `abd`):

   `SELECT * from pragma_foreign_key_list('abd');`
3. Do parsing to get what the list of tables of one-on-one relationships.

However, there must exist a more elegant way, I hope.

For SQL Server, there are `sys.foreign_keys` and `referenced_object_id` avaible (see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732406/4381271)). Maybe there is something similar to that in SQLite?

**Edit: adding two more tables for test**

```
-- tables 'ab' and 'abe' have a one-on-one relationship
CREATE TABLE abe (
    aid          INTEGER,
    bid          INTEGER,
    value        INTEGER       CHECK( value < 0 ),
    PRIMARY KEY (aid, bid)  FOREIGN KEY (aid, bid)  REFERENCES ab
);

-- tables 'ab' and 'abf' have a one-on-one relationship
CREATE TABLE abf (
    aidQ          INTEGER,
    bidQ          INTEGER,
    value        INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (aidQ, bidQ)  FOREIGN KEY (aidQ, bidQ)  REFERENCES ab(aid, bid)
);
```

**Edit: verify FK for table abe**

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
1
sqlite> .schema abe
CREATE TABLE abe (
    aid          INTEGER,
    bid          INTEGER,
    value        INTEGER       CHECK( value < 0 ),
    PRIMARY KEY (aid, bid)  FOREIGN KEY (aid, bid)  REFERENCES ab
);
sqlite> DELETE FROM abe;
sqlite> INSERT INTO abe (aid, bid, value) VALUES (2, 1, -21);
sqlite> INSERT INTO abe (aid, bid, value) VALUES (-2, 1, -21);
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
sqlite> SELECT * FROM ab;
1|1
1|2
2|1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative**

Although not a single query solution the following only requires submission/execution of a series of queries and is therefore platform independent.

It revolves around using two tables:-

- a working copy of sqlite_master
- a working table to store the the output of `SELECT pragma_foreign_key_list(?)`

Both tables are created via a CREATE-SELECT, although neither has any rows copied, so the tables are empty.

A trigger is applied to the working copy of sqlite_master to insert into the table that stores the result of SELECT pragma_foreign_key_list(table_name_from_insert);

The relevant rows are copied from sqlite_master via a SELECT INSERT and thus the triggering populates the store table.

The following is the testing code :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fklist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS master_copy;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS load_fklist;
/* Working version of foreign_key_list to store ALL results of SELECT pragma_foreign_key_list invocation */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fklist AS SELECT '' AS child,* 
    FROM pragma_foreign_key_list((SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'not a type' LIMIT 1));
/* Working version of sqlite master */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS master_copy AS SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'not a type';
/* Add an after insert trigger for master copy to add to fklist */
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS load_fklist 
    AFTER INSERT ON master_copy
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO fklist SELECT new.name,* FROM pragma_foreign_key_list(new.name);
    END
;

/* Populate master_copy from sqlite_master (relevant rows)
    and thus build the fklist
*/
INSERT INTO master_copy SELECT * 
    FROM sqlite_master 
    WHERE type = 'table' 
        AND instr(sql,' REFERENCES ') > 0
;
SELECT * FROM fklist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fklist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS master_copy;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS load_fklist;
```

Using a similar test base as per the previous answer the above results in :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Mike T. This works for all the test cases. However, I am hesitating to create tables and triggers. I may go back to my original idea of querying twice then parsing outside SQLite. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get a list of tables that have one-on-one relationship to a given table in SQLite3?

Not with certainty as coding a Foreign Key constraint does not define a relationship (rather it supports a relationship), that is relationships can exists without a FK constraint.

A Foreign Key constraint defines:-

- a) a rule that enforces referential integrity
- b) optionally maintains/alters referential integrity when the referred to column is changed (`ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` )

As such looking at the Foreign Key List only tells you where/if a FK constraint has been coded.

Saying that the following will get the tables with the constraint and the referenced tables.

*More elegant is a matter of opinion*, so it's up to you :-

```
WITH cte_part(name,reqd,rest) AS (
    SELECT name,'',substr(sql,instr(sql,' REFERENCES ') + 12)||' REFERENCES '
    FROM sqlite_master 
    WHERE sql LIKE '% REFERENCES %(%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        name,
        substr(rest,0,instr(rest,' REFERENCES ')),
        substr(rest,instr(rest,' REFERENCES ') + 12)
    FROM cte_part
    WHERE length(rest) > 12 
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN length(reqd) < 1 THEN name
        ELSE 
            CASE substr(reqd,1,1)
                WHEN '''' THEN substr(replace(reqd,substr(reqd,1,1),''),1,instr(reqd,'(')-3)
                WHEN '[' THEN substr(replace(replace(reqd,'[',''),']',''),1,instr(reqd,'(')-3)
                WHEN '`' THEN substr(replace(reqd,substr(reqd,1,1),''),1,instr(reqd,'(')-3)
                ELSE  substr(reqd,1,instr(reqd,'(')-1)
            END
    END AS tablename
FROM cte_part
;
```

As an example of it's use/results :-

[image]

- screenshot from Navicat

Here's an **adaptation of the above** that includes, where appropriate, the child table that references the parent :-

```
WITH cte_part(name,reqd,rest) AS (
    SELECT name,'',substr(sql,instr(sql,' REFERENCES ') + 12)||' REFERENCES '
    FROM sqlite_master 
    WHERE sql LIKE '% REFERENCES %(%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        name,
        substr(rest,0,instr(rest,' REFERENCES ')),
        substr(rest,instr(rest,' REFERENCES ') + 12)
    FROM cte_part
    WHERE length(rest) > 12 
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN length(reqd) < 1 THEN name
        ELSE 
            CASE substr(reqd,1,1)
                WHEN '''' THEN substr(replace(reqd,substr(reqd,1,1),''),1,instr(reqd,'(')-3)
                WHEN '[' THEN substr(replace(replace(reqd,'[',''),']',''),1,instr(reqd,'(')-3)
                WHEN '`' THEN substr(replace(reqd,substr(reqd,1,1),''),1,instr(reqd,'(')-3)
                ELSE  substr(reqd,1,instr(reqd,'(')-1)
            END
    END AS tablename,
    CASE WHEN length(reqd) < 1 THEN '' ELSE name END AS referrer
FROM cte_part
;
```

Example of the Result :-

[image]

- the **artists** table is referenced by **albums** as the SQL used to create the **albums** table is `CREATE TABLE 'albums'([AlbumId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,[Title] TEXT NOT NULL ,[ArtistId] INTEGER NOT NULL , FOREIGN KEY ([ArtistId])  REFERENCES 'artists'([ArtistId]))`
- i.e. `FOREIGN KEY ([ArtistId])  REFERENCES` **`'artists'`**`([ArtistId]))`
- the **employees** table is self-referencing as per `CREATE TABLE 'employees'(....  REFERENCES 'employees'([EmployeeId]))`

Additional re comment:-

> (I am still trying to understand your code...)

The code is based upon selecting rows from sqlite_master where the row is for a table (type = 'table'), as opposed to an index, trigger or view and  where the sql column contains the word REFERENCES with a space before and after and there is a following left parenthesis.

- The last condition used to weed out the likes of `` CREATE TABLE oops (`REFERENCES` TEXT, `x REFERENCES Y`); ``

For each selected row 3 columns are output:-

1. **name** which is the name of the table as extracted from the name column of sqlite_master,
2. **reqd** is initially an empty string (i.e. initial)
3. **rest** the rest of sql that follows the referred to table name with suffixed with REFERENCES.

The UNION ALL adds rows that are built upon what is newly added to the CTE, i.e. the three columns are extracted as per :-

1. **name** is the name
2. **reqd** is the sql from the rest column up until the first REFERENCES term (i.e. the table and referenced column(s))
3. **rest** is the sql from after the REFERENCES term

As with any recursion the end needs to be detected, this is when the entire sql statement has been reduced to being less than 12 (i.e the length of " REFERENCES ", the term used for splitting the sql statement).

This is what is termed as a [RECURSIVE CTE](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursive_common_table_expressions)

Finally the resultant CTE is then queried. If the reqd field is empty  then the tablename column is the name column otherwise (i.e. the reqd column contains data(part of the sql)) the table name is extracted (part up to left parenthesis if not enclosed (`,' or [ with ])) or extracted from between the enclosure.

The following is what the final query results in if all the CTE columns are included (some data has been truncated):-

[image]

As can clearly be seen the extracted sql progressively reduces

*The answer is intended as in-principle and has not been extensively tested to consider all scenarios, it may well need tailoring.*

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike T. Your code works for me.

Comment: Also here are some ideas related: 1) About  FK not defining but supporting a relationship: I think a one-on-one relationship not enforced by FK is a potential problem - in my case anyway. So in my case all one-on-one relationships must be constrained with FK and REFERNCES. (to be followed because of length limit)

Comment: 2) I will create more complicated cases to verify your code. I will test at least two cases. First, names of related columns in a parent and children could be different. Second, if names of related columns in a parent and children are the same, then REFERENCES can have the parent table name only, no names of columns followed.  (I am still trying to understand your code...) 3) Navicat, which you are using, seems very nice. First I used SqilteBrowser to run your code on my experimental database, and it gives me some wrong results. I could verify your code inside command line Sqlite3 though.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Mike T - I've been learning a lot. Also I added two table definitions, for the purpose of testing as I mentioned above. It seems that your code, even the adaptation version, cannot pick up table `abe`.

Comment: I noticed that you mentioned ON UPDATE /  ON DELETE with FK. In my real version of the table creation, they are there - and more.

Comment: @sofname Have you checked if **abe** is actually what you expect? I believe that syntactically it is incorrect as **ab** is not enclosed in parenthesises (surprised it isn't caught as an error by SQLite). See https://sqlite.org/syntax/foreign-key-clause.html. Also,  foreign_key_list('abe') shows both aid's and bid's **to** column to be null. Whether or not actions (**on update** or **on delete**)  are coded doesn't affect extracting the table name the key is the **REFERENCES** keyword followed by at lest one space space and a left parenthesis.

Comment: Yes `abe` is actually what I expected, @ Mike T.  That syntax is fine because `ab` is a `foreign-table`, not a `column-name` which must be enclosed in paranthesises, as specified in the link you mentioned. The FK behavior had also been verified by some INSERT statements - please check `Edit: verify FK for table abe` in my post.  Your observation on foreign_key_list('abe') is consistent with what i saw. However, Sqlite figures out foreign keys OK for this case, as long as `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; ` has been run.